# Is $\{X: \#X = \#S\}$, for some set $S$ a set? (without axiom of regularity)

Tags: set-theory

In ZF(C), is $C_S =\{X: \#X = \#S\}$, for some set $S\neq \emptyset$ a set? No, because then we would have an element of $C_S$ that contains $\{C_S\}$ and we get an infinite chain $\{C_S\} \in C_S \in \{C_S\} \in$ ..., which contradicts axiom of regularity.

But if we exclude the axiom of regularity, can such a set exist?

Comment: @bof cardinality of $X$.

Comment: @bof that was a mistake i corrected it now

Comment: Note if $C_1 = \{X\;:\; \#X = 1\}$ then $\bigcup C_1 = V$ the universe.  So now we will be able to write Russell's paradox.